# How do I write a input statement like this one. Purchase date:MM/DD/YYYY <input type="text" id="purchasedate" name="invoice_date" />

Tags: php, mysql

I am using this function as a calender drop down menu. I am not sure how to write the php `<inputtype ="text" ...`

This is the php function to generate the drop down . How do i write the `<inputtype="text"` statement ?

Sorry I am new to PHP and I can not figure out how to do this ?

```
<?PHP 

    FUNCTION DateSelector($inName, $useDate=0) 
    { 
        /* create array so we can name months */ 
        $monthName = ARRAY(1=> "January", "February", "March", 
            "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", 
            "September", "October", "November", "December"); 

        /* if date invalid or not supplied, use current time */ 
        IF($useDate == 0) 
        { 
            $useDate = TIME(); 
        } 

        /* make month selector */ 
        ECHO "<SELECT NAME=" . $inName . "Month>\n"; 
        FOR($currentMonth = 1; $currentMonth <= 12; $currentMonth++) 
        { 
            ECHO "<OPTION VALUE=\""; 
            ECHO INTVAL($currentMonth); 
            ECHO "\""; 
            IF(INTVAL(DATE( "m", $useDate))==$currentMonth) 
            { 
                ECHO " SELECTED"; 
            } 
            ECHO ">" . $monthName[$currentMonth] . "\n"; 
        } 
        ECHO "</SELECT>"; 

        /* make day selector */ 
        ECHO "<SELECT NAME=" . $inName . "Day>\n"; 
        FOR($currentDay=1; $currentDay <= 31; $currentDay++) 
        { 
            ECHO "<OPTION VALUE=\"$currentDay\""; 
            IF(INTVAL(DATE( "d", $useDate))==$currentDay) 
            { 
                ECHO " SELECTED"; 
            } 
            ECHO ">$currentDay\n"; 
        } 
        ECHO "</SELECT>"; 

        /* make year selector */ 
        ECHO "<SELECT NAME=" . $inName . "Year>\n"; 
        $startYear = DATE( "Y", $useDate); 
        FOR($currentYear = $startYear - 5; $currentYear <= $startYear+5;$currentYear++) 
        { 
            ECHO "<OPTION VALUE=\"$currentYear\""; 
            IF(DATE( "Y", $useDate)==$currentYear) 
            { 
                ECHO " SELECTED"; 
            } 
            ECHO ">$currentYear\n"; 
        } 
        ECHO "</SELECT>"; 

    } 
?> 

<HTML> 
<BODY> 
<FORM> 
Choose a Date: <?PHP DateSelector( "Sample"); ?> 
</FORM> 
</BODY> 
</HTML>
```

The end of my code .

Thank you in advance . Sorry I am new to PHP

Comment: php tip #1: don't write UPPERCASE CODE. There's no need to shout at yourself. PHP function calls and reserved words are not case sensitive, and it's common courtesy to NOT use all-caps for anything but constants.

Comment: Also, most people I know who write HTML use lower-case tags.

Comment: Thanks, you two were a big HELP !!!

Comment: It's not clear what you're looking for. Why do you need an `<input type="text">` for the date when you have the drop-down menus? What are you looking for other that `echo '<input type ="text" id="purchasedate" name="invoice_date" />';`?

Comment: I am trying to input the selected data from the drop down into a mysql database.

Comment: Usually I would use something like this. <input type="text" name="invoice_number" />. But I am not sure how to input the data from the drop down into my database ?

Comment: same as you would for the text, as long as it is in the form. One tip (when you don't know how your form will be posted) is to dump the `$_POST` when you post the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to add a text box for the date. You can just set them by concatenating the posted values

```
$selected_date = $_POST['SampleYear'] . $_POST['SampleMonth'] . $_POST['SampleDay'];
```

--

If you feel it necessary to have a `<input type="text" />` with the date, you can do this using jQuery

```
// in the head of your document
  //this checks for when elements of date are changed
$(function() {
$('#SampleMonth').change(function(){ setSelectedDate();});
$('#SampleDay').change(function(){ setSelectedDate();});
$('#SampleYear').change(function(){ setSelectedDate();});
}
  // this changes the text box to the values of the selects
Function setSelectedDate(){
var sel_month = $('#SampleMonth').val();
var sel_day = $('#SampleDay').val();
var sel_year = $('#SampleYear').val();
var new_sel_date = sel_year + "-" + sel_month + "-" + sel_day;
  // note that this puts the date as YYYY-MM-DD, which is the proper way to insert into mysql. It can be set as MM/DD/YYYY, but then you would have to change it again after posting.
$('#purchasedate').val(new_sel_date);
}

// inside the form tags
<input type="text" id="purchasedate" name="invoice_date" value="" readonly="true" />
```

Then you can input it in via the posted value

```
$selected_date = $_POST['purchasedate'];
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming post the date selected (in mysql format) will be:

```
$mysql_date=$_POST['SampleYear'].'-'.$_POST['SampleMonth'].'-'.$_POST['SampleDay'];
```

'Sample' being the value of $inName in the example